# How to track sorting in a datagridview

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

We've got a bunch of DataGridViews bound to a BindingSource, in turn bound to a SortableBindingList.

Since this control is a gigantic pain to use, I am trying to write a thin wrapper around it so the considerable amount of grid-related code can become more reuseable. By making it a generic class, GridWrapper, this also offers type safety advantages and "noise-free" code for common things like getting the selected item:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the item bound to the selected row if and only if exactly one row is selected; otherwise null.
/// </summary>
public T SelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        var rows = grid.SelectedRows;
        return (rows.Count == 1 ? rows[0].DataBoundItem as T : null);
    }
}
```

This leads to code like

```
var selectedCustomer = Customers.SelectedItem;
```

which is certainly easier both to write and to read than

```
Customer selectedCustomer;
if (customersGridView.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
   selectedCustomer = (Customer)customersGridView.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
```

and achieves the same. Anyway, so much for *why* I am writing a wrapper. My problem has to do with something else, which I'll now get to.

I'd like the wrapper to have the capability to know what a grid's default sorting should be, but also track sorting the user performs. This is for things like master-detail grids, where I'd like to retain the current sorting of the detail grid when it's rebound as a consequence of selecting another item in the master. So if I've sorted details by Column3 descending, I want the user code to do something like

```
Detail.Bind(GetDetailData(Master.SelectedItem));
```

where Detail is the wrapper for the details grid, and Master is the wrapper for the master grid.

To do this, I start off with a simple class to store sort state:

```
public class SortInfo
{
    public SortInfo(DataGridViewColumn col)
    {
        this.Column = col;
        this.Direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
    }

    public DataGridViewColumn Column;
    public ListSortDirection Direction;
}
```

The wrapper attaches a handler to the Sorted event of the grid in order to track user sorting. I also have a Sort method to *apply* the sort in my state object to a grid:

```
void Sort()
{
    if (GetBoundList() != null)
        grid.Sort(sortInfo.Column, sortInfo.Direction);
}
```

Pretty simple. (GetBoundList returns the SortableBindingList bound to the grid via a BindingSource, or null if doing so isn't possible.)

Now the problem: If I invoke Sort whenever the grid is bound, I get an InvalidOperationException complaining that the grid can only be sorted when bound to an IBindingList! That is weird to say the least, because the very last thing I do prior to invoking DataGridView.Sort is to check that so is the case.

In order to work around the above problem (hard to do anything else so long as I don't understand it!) I attempted to instead attach a handler to DataBindingComplete and invoke Sort there. This leads to another problem: When the user tries to sort the grid, the SortableBindingList resets bindings, which leads to DataBindingComplete firing. Since this happens before the list's ApplySortCore method (I think) returns, it also happens before the Sorted event. Hence, when the user tries to sort by Column2, my wrapper then sorts by Column1 (or whichever is the default), thus overriding the user sorting. The effect is very odd as you may see some rows move despite the same column header showing the same sort arrow; this is because the items *are* being sorted, they are just being sorted first as the user asked for and then by the default before you can really notice. The resulting order may be, if the column sorted by contains several equal values, different from the original order...

It seems to me that the problem has nothing to do with using a wrapper per se. That is to say, I'd have exactly the same issue if I tried to do this with all my code in a form, where I couldn't reuse it easily.

So the question is if anyone has an idea how to get around it. As I'm writing this one occurs to me: Attach the handler for DataBindingComplete only when binding data, and when it fires, sort the grid and then detach the handler. It seems to me this ought to solve both problems, actually.

However, since I've already written a ton I'll post this anyway! And if the idea above does work, I'll post it as answer.

Meanwhile, here's the wrapper code in the form that causes the "user sort is being overridden" form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Snippets.SortableGrid
{
    public class GridWrapper<T> where T: class
    {
        public GridWrapper(DataGridView grid, DataGridViewColumn defaultSortColumn)
        {
            this.sortInfo = new SortInfo(defaultSortColumn);
            this.grid = grid;
            grid.Sorted += new EventHandler(grid_Sorted);
            grid.DataBindingComplete += new DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(grid_DataBindingComplete);
        }


        public void Bind(IEnumerable<T> data)
        {
            BindingSource bs = grid.DataSource as BindingSource;
            if (bs == null)
                grid.DataSource = bs = new BindingSource();

            bs.DataSource = new SortableBindingList<T>(data);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the item bound to the selected row if and only if exactly one row is selected; otherwise null.
        /// </summary>
        public T SelectedItem
        {
            get
            {
                var rows = grid.SelectedRows;
                return (rows.Count == 1 ? rows[0].DataBoundItem as T : null);
            }
        }


        SortInfo sortInfo;
        DataGridView grid;


        ListSortDirection ToListSortDirection(SortOrder order)
        {
            return (order == SortOrder.Descending ? ListSortDirection.Descending : ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        }


        void Sort()
        {
            if (GetBoundList() != null && sortInfo.Column != null)
                grid.Sort(sortInfo.Column, sortInfo.Direction);
        }


        SortableBindingList<T> GetBoundList()
        {
            var bs = grid.DataSource as BindingSource;
            return (bs != null ? (bs.DataSource as SortableBindingList<T>) : null);
        }


        void grid_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            Sort();
        }


        void grid_Sorted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sortInfo.Column = grid.SortedColumn;
            sortInfo.Direction = ToListSortDirection(grid.SortOrder);
        }
    }


    public class SortInfo
    {
        public SortInfo(DataGridViewColumn col)
        {
            this.Column = col;
            this.Direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
        }

        public DataGridViewColumn Column;
        public ListSortDirection Direction;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your SortableBindingList does implement `IBindingList`, I hope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't exactly lived with this code for very long, but the idea does seem to work!

Change Bind to

```
public void Bind(IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    BindingSource bs = grid.DataSource as BindingSource;
    if (bs == null)
        grid.DataSource = bs = new BindingSource();

    grid.DataBindingComplete += new DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(grid_DataBindingComplete);
    bs.DataSource = new SortableBindingList<T>(data);
}
```

and the handler to

```
void grid_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    Sort();
    grid.DataBindingComplete -= grid_DataBindingComplete;
}
```

I can now rebind the "grid" (i.e. call GridWrapper.Bind with some new data) and the grid does "remember" it's sort state. Which is all I wanted to begin with.

--

I really don't understand why in 2013 it should be necessary to write any code at *all* for this kind of thing. The controls we get ought to have better support for common and useful stuff like this built-in.

While I'm ranting, I am also extremely sceptical of the whole idea that events is always the best way to hook in things. In a world where people try to do MVC or MVP or similar, why not give us something more closely aligned - something more akin to this wrapper - out of the box? It'd be so much easier to implement a view if the controls allowed you to at least in some respects treat them basically just as data structures.